# Make default landing tab load a 760px wide app

Tags: php, facebook-like

Is it possible to setup a fan page to work as follows?

1. User lands on my clients fan page
2. Sees a "Like me" graphic
3. User likes the page
4. User is then taken to a 760px wide app

The two parts i am struggling with are:

1. Creating a separate fan and none fan landing page
2. When liked, load up a 760px wide app

Do I control the like/nonlike graphic from my app using either PHP or Javascript by seeing if the user has already liked my app?
How do I force the liked page to load a 760px wide app?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can capture like button events.

[Facebook elements events](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.Event.subscribe/)

Example:

```
<script>
    window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
        FB.init({appId: '127654160646013', status: true, cookie: true, xfbml: true});
        FB.Canvas.setSize({ width: 520, height: 742 });
        FB.Event.subscribe('edge.create', function(response) {
            window.parent.location = ADDRESS;
        });
    };
    (function() {
        var e = document.createElement('script'); e.async = true;
        e.src = document.location.protocol + '//connect.facebook.net/lt_LT/all.js';
        document.getElementById('fb-root').appendChild(e);
    })();
</script>
```

Also you need get user fan status. Here is a solution:

```
<?
define('FACEBOOK_APP_ID', 'xxx');
define('FACEBOOK_APP_SECRET', 'xxx');

$is_fan = false;
if (!empty($_REQUEST['signed_request'])) {

    list($encoded_sig, $payload) = explode('.', $_REQUEST['signed_request'], 2);

    $sig = base64_decode(strtr($encoded_sig, '-_', '+/'));
    $data = json_decode(base64_decode(strtr($payload, '-_', '+/')), true);

    $expected_sig = hash_hmac('sha256', $payload, FACEBOOK_APP_SECRET, true);

    if ($sig == $expected_sig) {

        if (!empty($data['page']['liked'])) {
            $is_fan = true;
        }
    }
}
?>
```

There is everything you need. And just remember, you can redirect only via javascript:

```
window.parent.location = ADDRESS;
```

Comment: the code looks like its a way of handling the nonfan/fan page? is that correct? Does it also allow 760 wide apps?

Comment: Fan page can't contains more than 520px width iframe. You need make smaller fan page version. In additional, this fan status extractor work only in fan page (because apps don't send $_REQUEST['signed_request'])